# Unity Manual Instance Example Shader contains errors

Tags: unity, shaders

The Unity Manual has a [page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html) on GPU instancing. One of the examples, titled "Adding instancing to vertex and fragment Shaders", causes the following errors to printed to the console when saved in a Shader file:

```
... unrecognized identifier 'UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START' at line ... (on d3d11)
... not enough actual parameters for macro 'UNITY_ACCESS_INSTANCED_PROP' at line ... (on d3d11)
```

This error message does not make any sense. The identifier is supposed to be created in the [UnityInstancing.cginc](https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/CGIncludes/UnityInstancing.cginc) file, if the render target is supported. This thing is, d3d11 **is supported**:

```
Line 211: #ifdef UNITY_INSTANCING_AOS
    #define UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(buf)      
    ...
    #define UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(arr)
    ...
#endif

Line 41: #if defined(SHADER_API_D3D11) || ...
    #define UNITY_INSTANCING_AOS
#endif
```

**My question:**

Why does Unity say that these operations are not supported on this platform?

Comment: This sounds like an issue to report to the Unity engine development & documentation teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had a look at the copy of my (unaltered) UnityInstancing.cginc included with my own version of Unity. The `UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START` function does not exist in my copy, instead it is called `UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_START`. The `UNITY_ACCESS_INSTANCED_PROP` function also only takes one argument in my version.

To anybody who has similar problems with definitions not existing, I highly recommend looking at the file included with your version of unity. You may find, as I did, that the answer to your problem lies there!